# Different flex containers side by side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make it such that I have two half-width wrappers side by side. Currently the wrappers do take half the space but don't appear side to side. The `display:flex` seems to be taking the whole width and leaving the unused space on the side as margin.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Test Title</div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="column">
      <b>1</b>
      <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <b>2</b>
      <span>Two</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Test Title</div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="column">
      <b>1</b>
      <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <b>2</b>
      <span>Two</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried adding another div outside wrapper with width 50% but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: you have to put the wrapper in the parent div of those 2 divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `display: flex`, use `display: inline-flex`.

The first is a block-level element which, by default, takes the full width of the parent.

The second is an inline-level element, which can co-exist with other elements on the same line.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Test Title</div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="column">
      <b>1</b>
      <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <b>2</b>
      <span>Two</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Test Title</div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="column">
      <b>1</b>
      <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <b>2</b>
      <span>Two</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, set the parent element to `display: flex` which, by default, forces the children to exist in the same row.

Add this to your code: `body { display: flex }`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Test Title</div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="column">
      <b>1</b>
      <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <b>2</b>
      <span>Two</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Test Title</div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="column">
      <b>1</b>
      <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <b>2</b>
      <span>Two</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `display: flex` is similar to `display: block` if it's a top level element. The difference being; the children of the flex container will be able to utilize the flex behavior. What you need to do is something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #eee;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child column'>child 1</div>
  <div class='child column'>child 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the wrappers with div and then `display: flex`.

```css
.main-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">Test Title</div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="column">
        <b>1</b>
        <span>One</span>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <b>2</b>
        <span>Two</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">Test Title</div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="column">
        <b>1</b>
        <span>One</span>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <b>2</b>
        <span>Two</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```